# AChartEngine y-axis number range

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I'm using AChartEngine in my Android app.
In the line graph the default value of the difference between numbers on
y-axis numbers is always 500 or higher. How can I change this number?

For Example:

the values on the left side start  at 500 then 1000 then 1500 and I would like to set the 
first number to for example 100, then 200 etc. I can't find a good method in the library.

Kind regards!

Comment: How did u get a deafult value of 500 on y axis??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer` .. It's not enough means increase the value...

```
renderer.setYLabels(10);
```